# Overriding source macro in DBT to allow for dynamic sources for test runs

Tags: dbt

My aim is to be able to have "dynamic" sources depending on the type of DBT run I am doing. To be more precise, I am trying to find a solution to perform end-to-end business testing of our DBT models. I don't mean schema or simple data tests, but business logic tests. Something like, I have some input tables with test data, I run the DBT models and then I assert the end tables contain the desired results. I can create all the target tables in a separate schema by using a different 'test' profile, but I still need to be able to select from a different set of sources, which would be the test tables I am creating with the test data.

I guess I can use jinja in the source files in combination with some variables to make this happen, but I am wondering if there is an even better way where I can do it without changing the source files at all. Like, the developers would not have to worry about writing code that also works for the tests. For this purpose, I was wondering if we can override the source macro, or do something along these lines, to incorporate this behaviour - similar to when we override the `generate_schema_name` macro. Something along the lines of (in python pseudocode):

```
def source(schema_name, table_name):
    if env('is_test') == true:
        return schema_name + table_name + '_test'
    else:
        return schema_name + table_name
```

I guess the complexity here is also that the source macro does more than that, for example sets some info for the lineage for the docs, which I definitely would like to keep.

Any suggestion outside of this method are more than welcome!

Answer (score 3):

You can make your sources "dynamic" (i.e., configurable at runtime) using jinja in your `sources.yml` file itself, without writing any new macros. dbt doesn't allow macros or other complex jinja in `.yml` files, but you can access `var()`, `env_var()`, `target`, and use simple jinja conditionals to achieve this. You have to quote the jinja in your `.yml` file so the syntax doesn't collide with `.yml` syntax.

### Using a `unit_test` target

I would use a different target for unit tests (what I'm calling the kind of business logic tests you're looking for). Let's call it `unit_test`. So in your `profiles.yml`:

```yaml
profile: my_project_profile
target: dev # or unit_test if you want that to be the default
outputs:
  - name: unit_test # accesses unit test data
    ...
  - name: dev # accesses prod data
    ...
  - name: prod
    ...
```

By default, a source's name is the schema it selects from. However, you can override that behavior by using the `schema` key. So your `sources.yml` file becomes:

```yaml
version: 2

sources:
  - name: my_first_source
    schema: "{{ 'unit_test_source' if target.name == 'unit_test' else 'my_first_source' }}"
    tags: ["has_unit_tests"]
    tables:
      - name: my_first_table
        ...
```

If you want to keep the unit test data in the same schema as the real data, you can use this same trick to change the source table's name at runtime:

```yaml
version: 2

sources:
  - name: my_first_source
    tables:
      - name: my_first_table
        tags: ["has_unit_tests"]
        identifier: "{{ 'my_first_table_test' if target.name == 'unit_test' else 'my_first_table' }}"
        ...
```

You can then run dbt against your `unit_test` target; if you don't have unit test data built out for all models, you can select a subset of your dag to test using tags (I've added the `has_unit_tests` tag to the source above)

```bash
$ dbt build -t unit_test -s tag:has_unit_tests
```

### Using `var` or `env_var`

You can also access `var` and `env_var`. You could use these variables to either define the test relation identifiers, or just set a flag for `is_unit_test`. The first option, using `env_var` and setting a default value for when the environment variable is unset:

```yaml
version: 2

sources:
  - name: my_first_source
    schema: "{{ env_var('DBT_MY_FIRST_SOURCE_TEST_SCHEMA', 'my_first_source') }}"
    tags: ["has_unit_tests"]
    tables:
      - name: my_first_table
        ...
```

Then to run your tests:

```bash
$ export DBT_MY_FIRST_SOURCE_TEST_SCHEMA=my_first_source_test
$ dbt build -s tag:has_unit_tests
```

Answer (score 1):

My opinion that you should have separate database(s) for testing, plus having a variable for configuring the database name in `dbt_project.yml` file

So when to run the tests, you should be able to use `--vars` option.

Comment: I think that's generally speaking a good solution but unfortunately I don't think it applies to our case as we are on AWS Athena and AFAIK we only got 1 database (data catalog) for region. We can only play with schemas but not databases - hence the issue with the sources.

Comment: @Catazza: I haven't worked with AWS yet. But if it is the case, then can we use the schema as variable?

Answer (score 1):

Not positive if this is what you were looking for, but I've done some work with dynamic sources before. I needed to union 5 tables that lived in 5 separate schemas but had the same table name. I hope what I provide can at least get you moving in the right direction.

You have two tables:

`my_database.my_schema.tableA`

`my_database.my_schema.tableA_test`

So your sources file looks something like this:

```
-- src.yml

sources:
  - name: my_schema
    database: my_database
    tables:
      - name: tableA
      - name: tableA_test
```

You asked if there was any way to override existing macros like the generate macros. Unfortunately, I personally did not implement it that way for my situation because I didn't want to apply it to a larger scale (just a small portion of models).

Then I have my model:

```
-- my_model.sql

{%- set tbl = get_source(table_name) -%}

select 
    '{{tbl}}' as source,
    column1,
    column2,
    column3
from {{ source( 'my_schema' , tbl ) }} i
```

and that model calls on this macro to adjust the table name:

```
-- my_macro.sql

{% macro get_source(table_name) %}

{% if target.name = 'test' %}
{% set output = table_name ~ '_test' %}
{% else %}
{% set output = table_name %}
{% endif %}

{{ return(output) }}

{% endmacro %}
```

I have not tested this exactly, but I've gotten some version of dynamic schemas to work, so there is potential here. I may have misunderstood the ask too, so let me know if this is completely off.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @tconbeer's answer above for the inspiration for using an inline `if` [statement](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#if-expression) to define source credentials. I ended up using the below to help define where sources should come from depending on the profile being used.

```
sources:
  - name: source_name
    database: "{{ 'sandbox_user'if target.name == 'sandbox' else 'prod' }}"
    schema: "{{ 'sandbox_schema' if target.name == 'sandbox' else 'schema' }}"
```