# Overriding dbt source function with a basic passthrough macro fails

Tags: python, debugging, amazon-redshift, sandbox, dbt

I have this override of the ref macro in a file in the macros/ folder of my dbt project.

```
{%- macro ref(table_name) -%}

    {% set relation = builtins.ref(table_name) %}
    {% do return(relation) %}

{%- endmacro -%}
```

When I try to run any model using dbt run --models xxx this results in the error below:

```
Encountered an error:
keyword argument repeated: tags (<template>, line 12)
```

If I delete the file then dbt models run as expected.

I expect this macro to return the dbt Relation object just like the original dbt source function.

Have also tried overriding the source macro with the same result:

```
{%- macro source(source_name, table_name) -%}

    {% set rel = builtins.source(source_name, table_name) %}
    {{ rel }}

{%- endmacro -%}
```

and

```
{%- macro source(source_name, table_name) -%}

    {% set rel = builtins.source(source_name, table_name) %}
    {% do return(rel) %}

{%- endmacro -%}
```

I have seen similar usage here - overriding the source function - that's exactly what I'm trying to do: https://medium.com/checkout-com-techblog/dbt-modeling-at-scale-2614202bb5d0

Running with:

```
dbt-core==1.6.6
dbt-refshift==1.6.2
Python 3.9.13
```

I have checked similar questions but these do not answer my question above, for example:
[Overriding source macro in DBT to allow for dynamic sources for test runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70244607/overriding-source-macro-in-dbt-to-allow-for-dynamic-sources-for-test-runs)

Thanks in advance for any leads/advice!

Answer (score 0):

Overriding macros generally requires using the adapter dispatch config, I would assume the same applies to overriding the ref function too.

So e.g.

```
-- macros/ref.sql

{% macro ref(table_name) %}
    {{ return(adapter.dispatch('ref')(table_name)) }}
{% endmacro %}

{% macro default__ref(table_name) %}
    {% set relation = builtins.ref(table_name) %}
    {% do return(relation) %}
{% endmacro %}
```

See more here https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/dispatch

Hope this helps a bit forward!

Comment: Thanks! Tried this approach but unfortunately running into the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone gets a similar error, in the config of one of the dbt models the 'tags' parameter was defined twice, that caused the error.